# socket functions fails after two connect failure

Tags: c, sockets, websocket

```
while(1)
{
 if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1)
    {
        cout<<"Failed to obtain socket descriptor";
        continue;
    }

    /* Try to connect the remote */
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        cout << "Failed to Connect with Server\n";
        closesocket(sockfd);
        WSACleanup();
        continue;
    }
 recv(sockfd, revbuf, LENGTH, 0);
 closesocket(sockfd);
 WSACleanup();
 sleep(1000);
}
```

In above code, the socket functions fails after connect function fails two times. Since i am closing socket after connect failure, my socket function should be working all the time right? Can anyone explain why socket function is failing?

Comment: If the socket is not connected, don't try to close it.

Comment: @MartinJames tried it. still same issue.

Comment: You should check what is the error you get from the `connect()`, instead of assuming it failed; `connect()` can issue a `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error.